# How do I filter with OData based on an inner array?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

So I created a controller using the mvc4 web api where the url  (Get)  “/api/things” return the following data:

```
 <ArrayOfThing>
   <Thing>
   <Id>1</Id>
   <Description>The Thing Desc</Description>
   <Categories>
           <Category><Id>1</Id></Category>
          <Category><Id>2</Id></Category>
   </Categories>
  </Thing>
  <Thing>
   <Id>2</Id>
   <Description>The Other Thing Desc</Description>
   <Categories>
           <Category><Id>1</Id></Category>
           <Category><Id>3</Id></Category>
   </Categories>
  </Thing>
</ArrayOfThing>
```

*note that thing and categories has a many to many relationship

I know that if a need one “Thing” resource I should use a controller that matches the following route url  (Get)  “/api/things/{id}”.

But what if I want to get a subset of the data returned by the url  (Get)  “/api/things”.  I tested the OData protocol modifying the controller to return an IQueryable and it work fine if I wanted to $filter on the properties of “Thing” like the Id or the Description.  Unfortunately, I didn’t work out when I wanted to filter base on the Category, I believe is because Categories is an inner array.

So, what should I do to filter based on categories?

Answer (score 14):

OData V3 supports `Any`/`All` operations, which you can filter by a collection property. For example, to filter things which contains `Category(1)`, using following syntax:

```
/api/things/?$filter=Categories/any(category: category/Id eq 1)
```

If you are using ASP.net Web Api RTM bits, you can use [odata package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData) to support any/all. For more examples, you can check the queryable sample code: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/61dfed023e50#Samples%2fNet4%2fCS%2fWebApi%2fODataQueryableSample%2fProgram.cs

Comment: Life Saver! However, `contains` doesn't work on string containing xml. In my case I am trying to check "id" in string `"<key>id</key><value>1</value>"` . it gives me internal server error. Any idea what might be causing it